# Redis Pub/Sub with Python backend and Socket.io

Tags: php, python, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I have a PHP code which publishes data to a channel called "MESSAGE_FROM_MARS". The snippet is as follows :

```
    function send_data_to_check_spam($feedback)
    {
            $d_id=$this->redis_connect(11);
            //echo $feedback;
            //die();
            echo "<b style='color:red'>MESSAGE SENT TO SPAM SWATTER</b>"."<br>";
            $d_id->PUBLISH("MESSAGE_FROM_MARS",$feedback);

    }
```

There is a server side python listener which receives the published data and the snippet is as follows :

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=11)
def sum(a,b):
print a+b
def main():
  sub = r.pubsub()
  sub.subscribe('MESSAGE_FROM_MARS')
```

The python code does the processing and publishes the result back. The snippet is as follows :

```
r.publish('SPAM_STATUS',spam)
```

I am trying to get the result using a socket.io websocket and the snippet is as follows. :

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:6379');
console.log(socket);
socket.on('SPAM_STATUS', function (data) {
alert("here");
console.log(data);
//socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
</script>
```

Everything works like a peach except that the socket.io for some reason is not getting the message from the SPAM_STATUS channel.

What am I doing wrong? I am relatively new to socket.io, so pardon my naivety

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need a socketIO server on the server side.

So apparently, "var socket = io.connect('your redis port')" won't work.

Redis only comes in for the pub/sub part, which is for your server->server broadcast.

For realtime interaction between server and client side, you need a socketIO server AND socketIO client.

this is working example that I find very useful myself:

https://github.com/jonashagstedt/redis-pubsub-chat/tree/master/redischat